Is there a way to customize a PDF viewer in React without the preview being converted into an image?
I am developing a web application where I need to modify a PDF by embedding a QR code and displaying its preview while preserving the PDF format. The QR code will automatically embed (using qrcode) after a button click and then be displayed to the user in the PDF viewer. Currently, the only method I have found to achieve this is through iframe and embed tags.
I have also experimented with react-pdf and pdfjsLib but encountered issues with low preview quality due to the output being converted into an image. My main challenge with using iframe or embed is the limited customization options available. The primary issue lies in the standard PDF viewer itself, which lacks customization such as changing the toolbar, altering the color of the surroundings, and the inability to display page-by-page navigation instead of continuous scrolling.
pdf preview where output is converted into an image
standard pdf preview

A QRcode by its very nature is to all intents and purposes an "image" in a PDF so its definition must be perfect.
I have built an example of ONE QR Code with precision vectorised pixels at https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/qr-ansi.pdf
This illustrates that when not correctly defined in scalar values the definition is lost in some readers. Thus in a browser the ONE vector image at different scales responds poorly when wrong scale for the screen.

Compare that with the same WEB file in a "True" PDF browsing viewer.

The images you are generating are too small There is *no way their quality can be improved, whatever size you make them, Thus you need to CALCULATE exactly with precision the required pixel size.
This is supposed to be the "better" of your 2 examples it is certainly exceedingly sub standard. There should only be Black and White or any other 2 colours.

